# C# equivalent for Java's AudioFormat.isBigEndian and AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED

Tags: java, c#, audio, naudio

I am having hard time trying to port some Java code to C# for my simple project. The Java code makes use of **format.isBigEndian** and checks if the audio file data is **signed** or not. My C# project makes use of NAudio for handling audio files.

Here is the Java code

```
 public void LoadAudioStream(AudioInputStream inputStream) {
    AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
    sampleRate = (int) format.getSampleRate();
    bigEndian = format.isBigEndian();
    AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = format.getEncoding();
    if (encoding.equals(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED))
        dataIsSigned = true;
    else if (encoding.equals(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED))
        dataIsSigned = false;
}
```

and the C# code that I am working with..

```
     public void LoadAudioStream(WaveFileReader reader)
   {
       var format = reader.WaveFormat;
       sampleRate = format.SampleRate;
       //bigEndian = ??
       var encoding = format.Encoding;
       if (encoding.Equals( /*????*/))
       {
           dataIsSigned = true;
       }
       else if (encoding.Equals( /*?????*/))
       {
           dataIsSigned = false;
       }
   }
```

How can I check if the Audio file data is **big-endian** or not? and lastly is there a way to check if the AudioFormat is PCM **signed** or **unsigned**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCM WAV files use little endian. The most common bit depth is 16 bit, and this will be signed (ie short or Int16 in C#).

Comment: That explains it all! Thanks Heath.